# Increasing Pygame Image size after collision?

Tags: python, image, size, pygame, stretch

So I'm just learning how to work with classes and getting them to work between each different class. I'm trying to design a game where the user moves around and picks up food and each time the user picks up a piece of food the size of the character increases. I've done something similar before but now that there are classes involved I seem to have a hard time finding which class this should be part of. I added within the sprite update method that if it collides with a cherry then the size of the player should increase by 5 pixels each time. using the code :

```
self.Player.surface = pygame.transform.scale(self.Player.surface, (pwidth+5, pheight+5))
self.rect = self.Player.surface.get_rect()
```

Each time the game runs the player size doesn't change and for some reason the game no longer ends after the player has eaten a certain amount of cherries so I was just wondering if I was using a wrong method of changing the size of the player perhaps there may be an easier way to do so? Heres the rest of the code incase it helps at all.

```
import pygame, glob, random, time
from pygame.locals import *
from LabelClass import *

# CONSTANTS
WIDTH  = 400  # Window width
HEIGHT = 400  # Window height
BLACK  = (0,0,0) # Colors
WHITE  = (255,255,255)
BACKGR = BLACK  # Background Color
FOREGR = WHITE  # Foreground Color
FPS    = 40 # Frames per second
pwidth = 40
pheight = 40

class Food:
    def __init__(self,screen,centerx,centery):
        self.screen = screen
        self.surface = pygame.image.load('cherry.png')
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = centerx
        self.rect.centery = centery

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.surface,self.rect)
        #pygame.display.update([self.rect])


class Player:

    def __init__(self, screen, centerx, 
      centery, speed, backcolor):
        self.surface = pygame.image.load('player.png')
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = centerx
        self.rect.centery = centery
        self.speed = speed
        self.screen = screen
        self.backcolor = backcolor

        self.dir = ''

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.surface,self.rect)
        #pygame.display.update([self.rect])


    def move(self):
        if self.dir != '':
            if self.dir == 'd' and self.rect.bottom < HEIGHT:
                self.rect.top += self.speed
            if self.dir == 'u' and self.rect.top > 0:
                self.rect.top -= self.speed
            if self.dir == 'l' and self.rect.left > 0:
                self.rect.left -= self.speed
            if self.dir == 'r' and self.rect.right < WIDTH:
                self.rect.right += self.speed

    def jump(self,top,left):
        self.rect.top = top
        self.rect.left = left

class SpritesGame:

    def __init__(self,screen):

        self.screen = screen
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        pygame.display.update()
        music_file = getRandomMusic()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(music_file)
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1,0.0)
        self.music = True
        self.Foods = [ ]
        self.Eaten = 0



        for i in range(20):
            self.Foods.append(
              Food(self.screen,
              WIDTH*random.randint(1,9)//10,
              HEIGHT*random.randint(1,9)//10))
        for f in self.Foods:
            f.draw()
        self.Player = Player(screen,WIDTH//2,HEIGHT//2,6,BLACK)
        self.PickUpSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('pickup.wav')
        self.PlaySound = True
        self.startTime = time.clock()
        self.endTime = -1
        self.Won = False

    def update(self):
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)
        pickedUp = False
        for f in self.Foods[:]:

            if self.Player.rect.colliderect(f.rect):
                self.Foods.remove(f)
                self.Foods.append(Food(self.screen,WIDTH*random.randint(1,9)//10,HEIGHT*random.randint(1,9)//10))
                pickedUp = True
                self.Eaten += 1

                self.Player.surface = pygame.transform.scale(self.Player.surface, (pwidth+5, pheight+5))
                self.rect = self.Player.surface.get_rect()
                #self.rect.center = center



                print self.Eaten





        if pickedUp and self.PlaySound:
            self.PickUpSound.play()
        for f in self.Foods:
            f.draw()
        if self.Eaten == 40:
            self.Won = True
            self.endTime = time.clock()
        self.Player.move()
        self.Player.draw()
        pygame.display.update()

    def toggleMusic(self):
        self.music = not self.music
        if self.music:
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1,0.0)
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()


    def run(self):
        stop = False
        while not stop:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    stop = True
                if event.type == KEYDOWN: # Keeps moving as long as key down
                    if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                        self.Player.dir = 'l'
                    if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                        self.Player.dir = 'r'
                    if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                        self.Player.dir = 'u'
                    if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):                     
                        self.Player.dir = 'd'
                if event.type == KEYUP:
                    if event.key == ord('q'):
                        stop = True
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        stop = True
                    if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'): # End repetition.
                        self.Player.dir = ''
                    if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                        self.Player.dir = ''
                    if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                        self.Player.dir = ''
                    if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                        self.Player.dir = ''
                    if event.key == ord('x'):
                        top = random.randint(0,
                          HEIGHT - self.Player.rect.height)
                        left = random.randint(0,
                          WIDTH - self.Player.rect.width)
                        self.Player.jump(top,left)
                    if event.key == ord('m'):
                        self.toggleMusic()
                    if event.key == ord('p'):
                        self.PlaySound = not self.PlaySound 
            mainClock.tick(FPS)
            self.update()
            if self.Won:
                stop = True # END OF WHILE
        if self.Won:
            self.screen.fill(BLACK)
            pygame.display.update()
            msg = (str((int(self.endTime)
                       -int(self.startTime)))
                    +" seconds to finish. Hit Q.")
            L2 = Label(display,WIDTH//2,HEIGHT*7//8,26,msg,WHITE,BLACK)
            L2.draw()
            stop = False
            while not stop:
               for event in pygame.event.get():
                   if event.type == KEYUP:
                       if event.key == ord('q'):
                           stop = True
        pygame.event.get()
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()

def getRandomMusic():
    mfiles = glob.glob("*.wav")
    mfiles.append(glob.glob("*.mid"))
    r = random.randint(0,len(mfiles)-1)
    return mfiles[r]

def OpeningScreen(screen):
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.display.update()
    L1 = Label(display,WIDTH//2,HEIGHT*7//8,26,"Hit Q to Quit, P to Play.",WHITE, BLACK)
    L1.draw()

# Properly initiate pygame
pygame.init()
# pygame.key.set_repeat(INT,INT)
# Set the clock up
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Initialize Display
display = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Sprites and Sounds V06')

OpeningScreen(display)

stop = False
while not stop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            stop = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == ord('p'):
                game = SpritesGame(display)
                game.run()
                OpeningScreen(display)
            if event.key == ord('q'):
                stop = True


pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Surface.get_rect()` will always return a rect starting at `(0,0)`, and you also are modifying `SpritesGame.rect`. I think you should change

`self.rect = self.Player.surface.get_rect()`

to

`self.Player.rect.inflate_ip(5, 5)`

Comment: ive been trying to use this instead now but for some reason it still isnt growing.
                    self.Player.rect.inflate(1,1)

Comment: @user3188803 I would try `self.Player.rect.inflate_ip()` or `self.Player.rect = self.Player.rect.inflate()`